# My question concerns switching from using MathType in Word on a MacBook to using LaTeX in a word process for scientific papers

Tags: math-mode, embedding, word-to-latex, latex-to-word

For many (!) years I have written papers in MS Word with numerous embedded equations generated by MathType software. MathType prior to its recent acquisition by Wiris was able to function as a standalone equation editor and save equations as pdf files that could be embedded in Word, and edited either within Word on independently in the saved pdf format. The new version of MathType is an absolute disaster: the interface is pathetic with many controls of sizing and fonts lost, the generated equations are bit-mapped (not vector graphics), etc, etc.

**I hope to switch to producing all equations in manuscripts with LaTeX, but wonder whether some version of LaTeX can generate Word-embeddable pdf files, and if so what version(s) of LaTeX are suitable.**

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by word-embeddable pdf? are there constraints on the pdf it can handle?  If your document is in word though it will be more convenient to use word's built in math zones than embed pdf from latex

Comment: On a Mac probably the most popular way to export LaTeX equations for inclusion into other files is using [LaTeXIT](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/); an alternative that works on most major OS is [klatexformula](https://klatexformula.sourceforge.io/). Both, IIRC, can produce output in PDF format.